# shieldui datepicker formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, shieldui

I try to use shieldui datepicker like this

```
<input id="datepicker"/>  
 jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#datepicker").shieldDatePicker();
    });
```

also i add links

```
<script  src="https://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="https://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>
<link id="themecss" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/css/light/all.min.css" />
```

but datepicker is not display as expected I try this reference link 
[reference link](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/datepicker/basic-usage)

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjm44975/)

Comment: It works for me. Do you miss the styles? If so I just added it into the resources (as it should be in jsfiddle)

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>

<link id="themecss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/css/light/all.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js">      </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="picker" ></input>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
     $("#picker").shieldDatePicker({
      events: {
            change: function(e) {
                var date = new Date(e.target.value());
                var day = date.getDate();
                var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
                var year = date.getFullYear();

              alert("The Date is :" + day + "/" + monthIndex + "/" + year); 
            }
        }
    });
});

$("#picker").swidget().value(); // return null

$("#picker").swidget().value(new Date) // select the current date

$("#picker").swidget().value(); // return current selected date

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Click the date picker icon.

[image: Go to file and click download.]

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/gjm44975/2/  datepicker is display but without formatting

Comment: What formatting ? please describe more. https://jsbin.com/lihovelexi/3/edit?html,output

Comment: means that blue color and other style which is on calendar not apply when i try

Comment: check my above link.

Comment: i also try with same code in fiddle but not display

Comment: Now try download. click the file and download its working fro me. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: when i try this in htmlpage this work fine but when i try on webform1.aspx this shows error ... WebForm2.aspx:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117703/discussion-between-ranjan-satpathy-and-super-user).